# float object has no attribute 'number_of_day error in payroll module' in Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I got error `ValueError('<class \'AttributeError\'>: "\'float\' object has no attribute \'number_of_days\'" while evaluating\n\'result =-(contract.wage/31) * worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days\'')` when I'm trying to deduct Unpaid Leave from Payroll. I'm new in Odoo. Please help me.

I recently installed https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/om_hr_payroll/ this third party community edition.

I have created **Salary Rule** as like below Snapshot

[image: salary rule]

now, then I added that salary rule in **Salary Structures**

[image]

Now then when I click Compute Sheet in Employee Payslips then I got error as like below snapshot

[image]

I was seen this Blog post of this Module Provider Company https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/hr-unpaid-leaves-payroll-management-in-odoo-10

but still I got error in payroll

> My Odoo Version is latest odoo_15.0 (Community Edition)

Comment: Looks like `Unpaid` is type `float`. So, it can't have attributes like an object. You should look into this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/om_hr_payroll/ payroll module, then there are many object variables available for customize salary rule using python code section. see below I shared available variables list

```
# Available variables:
#----------------------
# payslip: object containing the payslips
# employee: hr.employee object
# contract: hr.contract object
# rules: object containing the rules code (previously computed)
# categories: object containing the computed salary rule categories (sum of amount of all rules belonging to that category).
# worked_days: object containing the computed worked days.
# inputs: object containing the computed inputs.

# Note: returned value have to be set in the variable 'result'
```

> wagePerDay = contract.wage // for get Wage from Contract

> totalWorkingDays = worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days // for get total working days (excluded public holidays, Sunday also... if you set Saturday off then Saturdays also)

> date2 = payslip.date_to // for get selected Payslip date_to

> date1 = payslip.date_from // for get selected Payslip date_from

```
Leaves = 0
for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
   Leaves += line.number_of_days // get number of leave (category wise like, total unpaid leave, total of paid leaves, total of sick leaves, total of Global Leaves)
```

Now below I shared my Final Answered for Deduct Unpaid Leave from salary

**This is Python condition field input**

```
unpaidLeaves = 0
for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
  if line.name == "Unpaid" and line.code == "UNPAID" :
    result = line.number_of_days
```

**This is Python code field input**

```
# Available variables:
#----------------------
# payslip: object containing the payslips
# employee: hr.employee object
# contract: hr.contract object
# rules: object containing the rules code (previously computed)
# categories: object containing the computed salary rule categories (sum of amount of all rules belonging to that category).
# worked_days: object containing the computed worked days.
# inputs: object containing the computed inputs.

# Note: returned value have to be set in the variable 'result'
# ---------------------

# totalWorkingDays = worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days
# date2 = payslip.date_to
# date1 = payslip.date_from
# sec_Of_1Day = 86400
# wagePerHour = contract.wage / 30 / employee.resource_calendar_id.hours_per_day

wagePerDay = contract.wage / 30
unpaidLeaves = 0
if worked_days.Unpaid and worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days or False:
  result= wagePerDay * unpaidLeaves
else:
  for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
    if line.name == "Unpaid" and line.code == "UNPAID" :
       unpaidLeaves = line.number_of_days

  
  result_qty = round(unpaidLeaves, 2)
  result = round(wagePerDay, 2)
  # result = wagePerDay
  # result = wagePerDay * unpaidLeaves
```

**See below Snapshot of Output**

[image: snapshot of Output]

you can see below snapshot of my answer

-: python condition :-
[image: snapshot of python condition]
-: python code :-
[image: snapshot of python code]

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will loop over `Worked Days` lines to add the lines to the `worked_days_dict` using their `code`

```
worked_days_dict = {}

payslip = self.env['hr.payslip'].browse(payslip_id)

for worked_days_line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
    worked_days_dict[worked_days_line.code] = worked_days_line
```

To use the following expression, you need to add a worked days line with `Unpaid` code :

```
result = (contract.wage/30) * worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days
```

*Note that the field name is : `number_of_days`*

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. but I solved my problem. I shared my answer. thank you so much. BTW I Up vote your answer. I think your answer is also right. actually I am Laravel Developer. I don't have to much idea in python.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggested answers,
One can calculate in python the unpaid leave amount with this **formular**:

```
wagePerDay = contract.wage / worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days      
totalUnpaidWage = wagePerDay*worked_days.LEAVE90.number_of_days;
result = round(totalUnpaidWage, 2)
```

Where:
**worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days**  is the total number of days worked for that month as recroded by odoo.

**worked_days.LEAVE90.number_of_days** is the number of unpaid leave.
The code **LEAVE90** can be configured under the tab **Unpaid Work Entry Type** which can be found when editing Salary Structure.

Find attached the example image from Odoo

[image]